# Is this behavior with the referrer when sending a XMLHttpRequest in Brave intended?

Tags: browser, xmlhttprequest, referrer

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'https://httpbin.org', true);
xhr.send();
```

When running this simple code above from `example.org`, request headers in Chrome devtools shows this:

```
Host:httpbin.org
Origin:http://example.org
Referer:http://example.org
```

When running the same code in Brave, I get this:

```
Host:httpbin.org
Origin:https://example.org
Referer:https://httpbin.org
```

I feel that that the referrer being the same that that the host is a bug, but maybe I'm missing something. Should I report this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is intended.

> We spoof cross-origin referer when '3rd party cookie block' is on.

[Source](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/3067)

Comment: it would be nice if this feature could be disabled in isolation.  The only way to use our site on Brave (which uses social signups via the referer) is to switch on 'All Cookies', which seems overkill.