# Brave browser support of Google API HTTP Referrer option

Tags: api, google-maps, http, referrer, brave

I'm using a Google API (e.g., for Maps Embed) with a key that is restricted via a list of **HTTP Referrers**. In this case, the map is embedded in my.site.com, so within the Google API -> Credentials page, I allow access for referrer *.site.com/*. When I visit my.site.com from most browsers, Google maps displays correctly as the browser sets the referrer field to my.site.com. When using the Brave browser, however, it sets the referrer field to the *origin* and displays an error:

**Request received from IP address 98.229.177.122, with referrer: https://www.google.com/**

Of course I could add google.com to the list of allowed referrers, but that defeats the purpose of limiting the use of the API key to my own website - anyone could "borrow" the API key, add it to their site for the same API, and anyone using Brave would be able to access the feature.  Now that each access costs $, I'd rather not do this. Any ideas for a work-around?

**Note:** @geocodezip - thanks for the reference. Indeed, I forgot to add that when I set the *site-specific* shield to "All cookies allowed", or even completely turn shields off for the site, the behavior is still the same (error). However, in the *default shield settings*, when I set the cookies field to "All cookies allowed", then it works as intended (maps are displayed), even though for the default settings section it states:

> These are the default Shields settings. They apply to all websites
>   **unless you change something in the Shields panel on a particular site.**
>   Changing these won't affect your existing per-site settings.

which I interpret to mean that the site-specific settings take precedence over the defaults.

So I'm thinking this (site-specific cookies setting not over-riding the default) is a brave bug, though that is a bit separate from my initial hope for a different approach that didn't require manual intervention on the user's part.

Comment: Looks like the Brave browser does that when '3rd party cookie block' is on. Related question: [Is this behavior with the referrer when sending a XMLHttpRequest in Brave intended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488690/is-this-behavior-with-the-referrer-when-sending-a-xmlhttprequest-in-brave-intend)

Comment: If google maps does this, they are actively breaking how the web should work. It might also be worthwhile to look at alternatives that don't have this problem.

Comment: Google Maps is saying "If we get a request from a referrer in your API key's access list, then honor the request." which it does for all other browsers. The issue is that Brave is intentionally changing the referrer (my.site.com) to instead be the originator (in this case, google.com), which is not in the access list. So if anything, it seems to me that Brave is "breaking things".